# C++ Redução do espaço gasto

Tags: c++, codeblocks, allegro

Estou criando um projeto em c++ com Allegro 5 usando o code::blocks, e coloquei os arquivos do allegro direto na pasta do projeto pra ficar mais simples. Estou usando funções apenas para mostrar imagens e textos com fontes ttf e detectar eventos do mouse e do teclado, porém, o allegro é muito maior que isso. Então meu projeto que deve ter usar uns 5 a 10 MB, acaba ficando com 80. Eu queria saber como identificar quais arquivos são redundantes e retirar.
Eu instalei o Allegro colocando as pastas `include` e `lib` na pasta `allegro`, dentro da pasta do projeto, e o conteúdo da pasta `bin` junto do programa compilado, fazendo os links necessários no code::blocks para que ele reconheça esses arquivos como parte do projeto. Então, o programa compilado, mesmo pequeno, depende dos arquivos dll e os da pasta `allegro`

Comment: A sua questão é como diminuir o tamanho do projeto propriamente dito, ou do programa depois de compilado?

Comment: Diminuir o tamanho do projeto, pois, se não me engano, não consigo usar o programa compilado sem estar na pasta do projeto

Comment: Você poderia instalar o Allegro fora do projeto e fazer a referência, onde o Allegro foi instalado, dentro do projeto. (resposta SO)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks]

Comment: @lemoce quando eu repassar o programa para o usuário, funcionará mesmo sem ele ter esses arquivos?

Comment: Ele terá que instalar a Allegro na máquina. Ou você pode criar um instalador e instalar as dll's nos diretórios corretos.

Comment: @lemoce Mas não tem como eu identificar o que eu não uso para poder economizar espaço?